# Why does my read() System Call Return -1?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I am doing a project in my class about file and i/o system calls. I have dumbed down the code below for the sake of my question. I have read the manual multiple times. I thought I understood read(), but clearly I'm missing something.

```
int a, bytesRead;
char buffer[150];

a = open("/home/JohnDoe/Dowloads/TestFile.dat", 0);
if (a < 0) {
    printf("Error opening file TestFile.dat\n");
    return 0;
}

bytesRead = read(a, buffer, 150);
printf("Bytes read: %d\n", bytesRead);
```

I'm lost to as why this read() call returns -1. If I understand the manual correctly, read() takes arguments file id, buffer and number of bytes to read. The integer, a (file id), was returned without error, I created my buffer and reading 150 bytes should be no problem because the file contains well over 150 bytes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to see what's wrong. You can get a nice message using [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) or print it using [`perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html).

Comment: I really doubt you have a file named `~/Dowloads/TestFile.dat`. You really have a directory called `~`?

Comment: On another note, please don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you want to open a file read-only use the proper `O_RDONLY` flag.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My apologies. I included the full file path now with user "JohnDoe." That brings up one other question. Given that this source file will be sent to my grader, how do I get this open to work on their machine as well, because they very likely won't have the same user name as me? Sorry, I'm fairly new to the stuff. And yes, I fixed the magic numbers in my code. My professor only provided the magic numbers, so I did some digging in  fcntl.h

Comment: Regarding the path issue, you could use relative paths, and have it well-documented. Or you could use a command-line argument to provide the path, or read it in your program.

Comment: Does the edited version still return -1? If that works, then please revert the edit, as it makes no sense to ask about error in code different than what is shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check [errno](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). If read returns -1, the errno will be set and you can see, where the error happened.